# How to dynamically change font-size of :before element in pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, tinymce

I want to change the size of the before pseudo-element dynamically, according to to font-size of the element, that the pseudo-element is set to.

I use TinyMCE v4. I have added a style format as follows:

```
style_formats: [
    {
      title: 'Custom Bullet',
      selector: 'ul', 
      classes: 'custom_bullet'
    },
]
```

I add following style with this format:

```
.custom_bullet li:before{
    content: "\e013";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    float: left;
    color: #F00;
}
```

What I want to get, is that when I change font-size of li, the li custom marker should also change dynamically.

I could do it with JS, but that's what i want to avoid. I would like to find a solution based on CSS.

Comment: That should already be the default behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/w7u92dvg/ Are you specifying font size for the :before content somewhere?

Comment: No, font-size is not specified anywhere else, but i got what is wrong.
When TinyMCE creates ul list, he creates something like this
ul > li+span, and the span contains the edited tekst. So before element of span can't inherit the proper font-size.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but what about:

```
.custom_bullet li, .custom_bullet li:before {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Comment: That's not dynamic.. =/

Answer (score -2):

Don't write the font-family in quotes

```
font-family: Glyphicons Halflings;
.custom_bullet li:before{
    content: "\e013";
    font-family: Glyphicons Halflings;
    float: left;
    color: #F00;
}
```

Comment: Saying "Don't write the font-family in quotes" is both wrong and unrelated to the question.