# how can I format the text size in a pseudo class ::after

Tags: css, pseudo-class, text-size

I want to format the size of the text inside of a `::after` pseudo element.

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

#Seite1::after,
.DivTableRotated::after {
    content: "Die Prüfergebnisse beziehen sich ausschließlich auf die Prüfgegenstände. Die auszugsweise Vervielfältigung des Berichts ist nicht zulässig.";
}
```

```html
<div id="Seite1"></div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your requirement. If its just change the font properties of the content text you can use regular font properties in the pseudo class.

Comment: Please describe more specifically

Comment: The same way as you style text size in any other element using css... `font-size`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically change font-size of :before element in pure CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139361/how-to-dynamically-change-font-size-of-before-element-in-pure-css) can ignore the "dynamic" as this literally explains how to change the textsize in pseudo elements

Answer (score 0):

You can style it just as any other element. Below is provided simple example. If there is something more specific you want to change, please comment or update your post.

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

#Seite1::after,
.DivTableRotated::after {
    content: "Die Prüfergebnisse beziehen sich ausschließlich auf die Prüfgegenstände. Die auszugsweise Vervielfältigung des Berichts ist nicht zulässig.";
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="Seite1"></div>
```